# Email header blocking the link?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this header:

```
$headers = array( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' );
```

And this kind of message:

```
$redirectUrl=network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login');
$message .= '<a href="'.$redirecturl.'">'.$redirectUrl.'</a>';
```

If i print this message in localhost it shows the link, all good.
But. when i email this message, the link is not shown in the email.

```
wp_mail( $user_data->user_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

And if i donot use the `$headers` all good again. What am  I doing wrong?

Comment: try with `$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";`

Comment: Or try with `$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";`

Answer (score 0):

As extract from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

> The default content type is ‘text/plain’ which does not allow using HTML. However, you can set the content type of the email by using the ‘wp_mail_content_type’ filter.

In that case try adding this to your functions.php

```
function set_content_type(){
    return "text/html";
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','set_content_type' );
```